# is it require to put content provider code in thread

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

i am using `ContentProvider` to access database and building JSON request to send data over HTTP inside my `Service` class.

sudo code is as follows

```
    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
            DB.EMPLOYEE_URI,
            DB.EMPLOYEE.PROJECTION,
            null, null, null);

     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        Employee  empInfo= new Employee();

            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DB.EMPLOYEE.COL._ID));
            String name= cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DB.EMPLOYEE.COL.EMPLOYEE_NAME));

       String reqJSON =  getGSON()
                .toJson(empInfo);

     }
```

so do i need to wrap it up above code inside a thread or async task so that it wont interrupt the main thread , as i am not sure getContentResolver is non block-able operation.

Answer (score 0):

No but i would, def if you got to filter, you dont rlly want to block the UI thread. Just use ASyncTask, so you dont need to handle the thread's life cycle.